# About relation in linear polynomial over linear polynomial with matrices.

Tags: matrices, rational-functions

> I was analyzing rational expressions involving linear polynomial over linear polynomial of the form:
> $${ax+b \over cx+d},\;\text{where $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R$};$$
> Amazingly, these polynomials have some properties related to that of matrices of the form:
> $$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix};$$
> If we consider, $f(x) = \cfrac{ax+b}{cx+d};$ equivalent to $F=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix};$ for instance.
>
> We will find that $f^{-1}(x)$ is equivalent to $\operatorname{adj} F$.
>
> Here's how.
> $$\begin{align}
> f(x)=y&=\cfrac{ax+b}{cx+d};&F=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix};\\ \\
> (cx+d)y&=ax+b;\\
> cxy+dy&=ax+b;\\
> x(cy-a)&=-dy+b;\\
> x&=\cfrac{-dy+b}{cy-a}&=\cfrac{dy-b}{-cy+a}; \\ \\
> f^{-1}(x)&=\cfrac{dy-b}{-cy+a};&\operatorname{adj}F=\begin{pmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{pmatrix};
> \end{align}$$
> Amazingly, function compositions also are related to matrices. Take a look at this.
> $$\text{let}\; f(x)=\cfrac{ax+b}{cx+d} \;\text{ and }\; g(x)=\cfrac{px+q}{rx+s};\\
> F=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix} \;\text{ and }\; G=\begin{pmatrix}p&q\\r&s\end{pmatrix};\\
> \begin{align}
> f\circ g(x)&=\cfrac{a\cdot g(x)+b}{c\cdot g(x)+d};\\
> &=\cfrac{a{px+q\over rx+s}+b}{c{px+q\over rx+s}+d} \times {rx+s\over rx+s};\\
> &=\cfrac{a(px+q)+b(rx+s)}{c(px+q)+d(rx+s)};\\
> f\circ g(x)&=\cfrac{(ap+br)x+(aq+bs)}{(cp+dr)x+(cq+ds)};\\ \\
> FG&=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}p&q\\r&s\end{pmatrix};\\
> FG&=\begin{pmatrix}ap+br&aq+bs\\cq+dr&cq+ds\end{pmatrix};
> \end{align}$$

Clearly, if we relate functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ with matrices $F$ and $G$. Then, $f^{-1}(x)$ can be related to $\operatorname{adj} F$ and $f \circ g \; (x)$ can be related to $FG$.

Finally, after with all this long story, the main questions are:

1. Was it known before, if yes does it have a name?
2. Why does it happen, does it explain why matrices operations were defined like this? *i.e.* When creators of **Matrix** were defining Matrix multiplications and Adjoint Matrix, they were thinking about all this?
3. **Main question:** Can this be somehow related to 3 quadratic equations somehow using something?

Answer (score 1):

Good noticing!  This connection is well known; see the Wikipedia article  [Möbius transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation).